# Fix the first row of a HTML table

Tags: html, css, html-table

I want to make the first row of a HTML table always visible when the user scrolls down the page.

I tried to style it as "position: fixed", but the problem is that when I do that, **the cells of the first row start to have different widths compared to the cells of the other rows**.

My table is styled as "table-layout: fixed, width: 100%".

Do you know why please?

Comment: Please do place you tried HTML code below or in fiddle.. and not way to ask question like this...

Answer (score 0):

in your css

```
tr{ position:absolute; }
```